# Node 8.0 New Symbols And Adding Space After Symbol For Number.prototype.toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, currency

I just updated to Node v8.0 and noticed that Number.prototype.toLocaleString() with options `style: 'currency'` and also `currency` set to any currency behaves differently than any other environment.  In Node v7.2.1 and also Chrome v58.0 my output would look like `$5.00`, but in Node 8 it's showing with different currency symbol and extra space as `US$ 5.00`. Is this just an update? Where would I find docs for this?  Did Node just decide to update `toLocaleString` and it should be treated as a function that changes based on environment?

`const value = 5`

`value.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' })`

Node 8.0

`'US$ 5.00'`

Node < 8.0 + Chrome

`'$5.00'`

Comment: I just tested in on node v8.0.0 and it all works as expected... https://image.prntscr.com/image/7de7c2b02cfa4faaaf84daa5da8f98b5.png

Comment: you can find documentation here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: It looks like the error I was getting was when no locale is provided, so `value.toLocaleString(undefined, { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' })`.  I guess the default locale is no longer `en-US` so that was causing my issue.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @user7128475 so if `en-US` is no longer valid, what is the new valid one?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error I was getting was when no locale is provided, so `value.toLocaleString(undefined, { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' })`. I guess the default locale is no longer `en-US` so that was causing my issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

> Should it be treated as a function that changes based on environment?

Yes, definitely. From [ECMA-402 §13.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-Number.prototype.toLocaleString) and [§11.3.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-number-format-functions):

"*The computations rely on String values and locations within numeric strings that are dependent upon the implementation and the effective locale […]*"

even though it notes that

"*It is recommended that implementations use the locale data provided by the Common Locale Data Repository (available at http://cldr.unicode.org/).*"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the "icu." The version of Node you are using does not include a "full-icu" by default. I found two approaches to solve the problem. The first involves giving node a full-icu at runtime. The second involves compiling Node from scratch including the full-icu.

**Runtime Approach**

Say you have Node `8.11.1` installed. Install the [npm package `full-icu`](https://github.com/unicode-org/full-icu-npm) globally.

```
npm install -g full-icu
```

Read the command line messages to see where your `full-icu` file was installed. You will need that when you specify the --icu-data-dir option when calling the `node` command. For example:

```
node --icu-data-dir=/some/where/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/full-icu Your-App.js
```

Replace `Your-App.js` with your program. You may also install the `full-icu` package locally and use `./nodule_modules/full-icu` for the `icu-data-dir`.

Ref: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/intl.html#intl_providing_icu_data_at_runtime

**Compile Approach**

This approach involves compiling Node from scratch, specifying an option to include the `full-icu` in the build. I suggest [using NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm):

```
nvm use 6
nvm uninstall 8
nvm install -s v8 --with-intl=full-icu --download=all
```

The above temporarily switches your Node version beforehand so that you may uninstall the Node 8 version before installing a new v8. Don't skip that step! It may take a while to build Node.

(If you don't have the version 6 above, install it using `nvm install 6` or use another different from 8)

Ref: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1719